# posgres error "collation "default.pg_catalog" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, loopbackjs

I have no idea what this is about, I am trying to run the following SQL, but I get this error:

```
collation "default.pg_catalog" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
```

the SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE public.account
(
    sales_region__c character varying(40) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    parent_industry_group__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    pricing_type__c character varying(50) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    accountnumber character varying(40) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    vat_registration_number__c character varying(30) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    language__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    account_uuid__c character varying(200) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    billingstreet character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    ispartner__c boolean,
    address1__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    currencyisocode character varying(3) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    company_registration_number__c character varying(30) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    parent_industry_mix__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    lastmodifiedbyid character varying(18) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    isservicecenter__c boolean,
    county__c character varying(50) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    embargo__c boolean,
    export_control_status__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    customer_name__c character varying(100) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    geocode_status__c character varying(50) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    type character varying(40) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    ownerid character varying(18) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    parentid character varying(18) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    industry_group__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    createdbyid character varying(18) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    sv_status__c character varying(30) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    industry character varying(40) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    address3__c character varying(100) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    email__c character varying(80) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    var_contact_language__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    vendor_type__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    account_local_name__c character varying(250) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    customer_account_group__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    createddate timestamp without time zone,
    supress_renewal_messaging__c boolean,
    parent_industry_group_summary__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    billingstate character varying(80) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    parent_industry_segment__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    mark_for_deletion__c boolean,
    state_province__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    auto_assignment__c boolean,
    billingcity character varying(40) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    group__c character varying(25) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    is_partner_certified__c boolean,
    notify_language__c character varying(30) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    account_csn__c character varying(30) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog NOT NULL,
    city__c character varying(50) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    industry_segment__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    issupportcenter__c boolean,
    export_control_notes__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    fax character varying(40) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    license_compliance__c boolean,
    alias__c character varying(100) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    renewal_url__c character varying(100) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    status__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    partner_type__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    upsellopportunity__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    lastmodifieddate timestamp without time zone,
    support_contact__c character varying(18) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    phone character varying(40) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    gp_account__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    partner_support_prov_flag__c boolean,
    registration_number__c character varying(30) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    partner_flag__c boolean,
    geo__c character varying(20) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    billingcountry character varying(80) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    address2__c character varying(100) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    parent_account_csn__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    individual_flag__c boolean,
    support_provision_flag__c boolean,
    account_type__c character varying(30) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    ispartner boolean,
    name character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    billingpostalcode character varying(20) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    zip_postal__c character varying(30) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    sec_city__c character varying(50) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    iscustomerportal boolean,
    sub_region__c character varying(40) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    isdeleted boolean,
    language_code__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    active__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    slaexpirationdate__c date,
    primary_partner_program__c character varying(15) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    country__c character varying(50) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    rfr_email_addr__c character varying(50) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    systemmodstamp timestamp without time zone,
    pricing_group__c character varying(50) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    global_agreement__c character varying(15) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    parent_named_account_group__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    slaserialnumber__c character varying(10) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    industry_sub_segment__c character varying(1300) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    end_customer_agreement_number__c character varying(100) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    parent_sales_org__c character varying(255) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    local_language_name__c character varying(100) COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_account" PRIMARY KEY (account_csn__c)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.account
OWNER to "SPRUCEPOSTGRESSDB2";
```

any idea?

My end goal is to replicate our production postgresql db in a Docker container. Perhaps there is a better way to do this than to manually clone?

Answer (score 3):

change `"default".pg_catalog`  to `pg_catalog."default"`

Answer (score 0):

If it is in upper case make make it to lower case. It worked for me.
Change

```
 COLLATE PG_CATALOG."DEFAULT"
```

to

```
collate pg_catalog."default"
```